# How to delete Bingo Bash data game from iPad

Tags: ipad, facebook

I downloaded Bingo Bash, which links to their server. Whenever I delete it and re-install it back, it will come back to the level that I was last playing.

How can I totally remove all the game data and play it from the start? And I also mistakenly connected with my Facebook account. Now when I play with my iPad, the same level also happens in my Facebook account - I'd like to disconnect this, and start the game from scratch.

Comment: Are you asking how to remove the game from your iPad, or how to remove your Facebook account from the game?

Comment: Sorry, I mean I downloaded Bingo Bash that link to the server, Whenever I deleted it and re-install it back, it will come back to the level that I play. May I know how can I totally remove all the data and play it from the start? And I also mistakenly connected with my facebook account. now I play with my ipad the same level also happens in my facebook account. Anyway, I just hope I can totally remove the game from scratch.

Comment: That's a good question, but I believe the answer will be specific to how the Bingo Bash game is implemented - do they have some kind of account settings on the iPhone or Facebook apps, or on their website, that let you reset your account? That might be one place to look.

Comment: I've search around. No reset account can be found anywhere. I think this is link to their server.

Comment: Your "profile" is saved on they server. Try going there and see if you can reset it. Alternatively, you need to log in with new credentials.

Answer (score 1):

Apple doesn't implement a user method to delete data stored in iCloud or Game Center.

You need to ask the developer to make that code in the app itself. I'm fairly certain a program that can write data can also clear it - but it's really up to them to implement that call to Apple's API in [GameKit](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/GameKit/Reference/GameKit_Collection/) and [CloudKit](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/CloudKit/Reference/CloudKit_Framework_Reference/index.html) respectively.

See:

- [How do I delete data for one game in the iPad Game Center?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/25371/how-do-i-delete-data-for-one-game-in-the-ipad-game-center)