# I need to delete a game app data from iCloud but not my iPad

Tags: ipad, icloud, game-center

I have a game where a glitch in the system has caused the Game Centre data in iCloud to be out of sync with the game on my iPad.

I want to delete the iCloud data and then reconnect the game so it then loads the data from the existing progress in the iPad back to iCloud / Game Centre - any ideas.

**Please do not post on tips how to delete the app from the iPad.**

Comment: Related: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/228407/deleting-app-data-from-game-center?rq=1, https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/25371/how-do-i-delete-data-for-one-game-in-the-ipad-game-center?rq=1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Deleting app data from Game Center](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/228407/deleting-app-data-from-game-center)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I delete data for one game in the iPad Game Center?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/25371/how-do-i-delete-data-for-one-game-in-the-ipad-game-center)

Answer (score 1):

If the data is backed up on iCloud. You can manage the storage on your Mac.

System Preferences -> iCloud -> Manage Storage -> Select the Backed Up Game -> "Delete Documents and Data"

[image]